# Lumia 1020 xenon flash is not working

Tags: camera, nokia-lumia-1020

Even though my flash setting is ON, it doesn't fire during taking a photo. Just the focus assisting LED flash only fires. Is the xenon flash bulb faulty? Is it a software problem? Hard reset also didnt solve this problem.

Comment: sounds like a hardware fault - have you taken it to a service centre?

Comment: i bought it on ebay. raised a claim for exchange. i thought if it was software issue, then maybe i can fix it